# How to make my app only on iPhone 4S and higher?

Tags: app-store-connect

My app is for a smart device and uses Bluetooth Low Energy. I would like to enable my app only for iPhone 4S and higher. Is that possible ?

Comment: Ask on StackOverflow. Ask Different isn't for software development.

Comment: @Arc676 Even if the answer would have been some option in iTunes Connect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restrict your app to [devices having certain capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html).

In the `Info.plist` file add a new key `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` with an array as value. You can put all your required capabilities in the array. In this case `bluetooth-le`.